# Display an Image in html page based on user specifed url

Tags: javascript, html

Some background

My website shows existing image and new image at top of page.
The user can specify **Browse** to find a local image and code will automatically replace new image with selected file.
The user can also do **Artwork Search**, this will open Google Image search on new tab, they can drag image from that tab on to the area marked **DropZone**, and again javascript will automatically replace new image with selected file.

[image]

But this is awkward to do on an iPad so I am trying to add 3rd option, let the user specify an **Artwork Url**, select **Upload** and this will again automatically replace new image with selected file. But Im struggling to get it working

My existing javascript for uploading a file from desktop is

```
function uploadImageFile(filelist)
{
    img =
    {
        type: 'file',
        element: new Image(),
        file: filelist[0]
    };
    img.element.src = URL.createObjectURL(img.file);
    img.element.onload
        = function() {
        res.src=img.element.src;
        resCaption.innerHTML=img.element.width + " x " + img.element.height + " (" + img.file.type.split('/').pop().toUpperCase() + ")";
    }
}
```

in the html the new Artwork has id of res

```
<img id="res" src="style/images/new_artwork.jpg" class="figure-img rounded">
```

So Im trying to write a similar javascript function when the user clicks on the **Upload** button after having pasted the image url but its not working

```
function uploadUrl()
{
    img =
    {
        type: 'file',
        element: new Image()
    };
    img.element.src = document.getElementById("paste_artwork_url");
    img.element.onload
        = function() {
        res.src=img.element.src;
        resCaption.innerHTML=img.element.width + " x " + img.element.height + " (" + img.file.type.split('/').pop().toUpperCase() + ")";
    }
}
```

The Upload button triggers the javascript function okay, html is

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-outline-link" id="copy_paste_button" type="button" onclick="uploadUrl();">
                                                            Upload
                                                        </button>
```

Comment: Please provide the code needed to create a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) preferably as a snippet (`<>` Icon).

Comment: It's unlikely this is causing the problem, but in general you should set your `onload` before setting `src` just in case the image is already cached.

Comment: @MarkBaijens im at my limit of html/javascript here, the issue is clearly that by uploadUrl() function is wrong, Im not setting the file element like I am in uploadImageFile() function, or maybe src is set wrong, but the info is in question

Comment: @PaulTaylor Your missing HTML that is needed to run the JavaScript. For example you retrieve the element with the id `paste_artwork_url` but never mention it in the html. Read the article I linked and you will learn how to provide a good question we can easily debug without the need of rewriting your code.

Comment: `img.element.src = document.getElementById("paste_artwork_url");` you are trying to assign the reference to an HTML element as the image source here, that makes no sense. Assuming that the element with ID `paste_artwork_url` is an input field, that should be `img.element.src = document.getElementById("paste_artwork_url").value;`

Comment: The button html is at the bottom of the question

Answer (score 0):

Listen, if you want to preview an image, here are some situations :

**1. the URL :**
when uploading a link, it is enough to get the URL from an input :

```js
const input = document.getElementById("input")
const prev = document.getElementById("src")
input.onchange = function() {
prev.src = input.src
}
input.oninput = input.onchange
```

**2. The file uploading :** 
and this is also one of the easy things by using the `FileReader` class :

```js
const input = document.getElementById("input")
const prev = document.getElementById("src")

input.onchange = function(){
let fileReader = new FileReader()
let file = input.files[0]
fileReader.readAsDataURL(file) // and you can use fileReader.readAsText(file) if you want to read a file content
fileReader.onload = function(){
prev.src = fileReader.result
}
}
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: HI, 1. is useful i have now have image displayed, but I dont understand 2 you have file.input.files[0] but I dont have a file only a url

Comment: @PaulTaylor, the fileInput.files[0] is the first file selected in the file input, as there are multiple files selected at the same input (when the multiple attribute attached with the `<file type="input" />` you can google it